# How to numerically assign dimensions of a face

Tags: modeling

I would like to make a truncated cone, with the base and top of specific diameters.

First I made a cylinder mesh and input the width and length of the cylinder to match the base.

That's good.

Then I selected the top face and tried to scale it down to the width and height for the top of the cone, but I can only adjust it with my mouse or as a percentage of the original size.

Is there a way to adjust the face's absolute diameter by entering a number like I did the whole object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way is to first create the bottom/top face numerically, then adjust the height, which can also be done numerically. As shown below:

[image]